# Exiting out of a loop using while or do while

Tags: c++, loops

**This is for school**

I'm using the same implementation that I used for a previous project where I just make a terminate variable then break out of my loop when that terminate variable is read. However, for this program that I wrote, my exit statement just reads in the user input and continues with the program. I have tried both a while loop and do while loop.

Here is my program

---

```
int main() {
  std::string input;
  std::string terminate = "end";
  std::transform(terminate.begin(), terminate.end(), terminate.begin(),::toupper); //Extra stuff makes it not case sensitive

  std::cout << "This program checks for a balanced expression" << std::endl << "Enter 'end' to end the program" << std::endl;

  while(input != terminate){
    std::cout << "Enter Expression: ";
    std::cin >> input;

    if(checkBalance(input))
      std::cout << input << " " << "is balanced" << std::endl;
    else
      std::cout << input << " " << "is not balanced" << std::endl;


    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Extra stuff makes it not case sensitive" no, it does not.

Comment: `terminate ` will be made all caps, not case insensitive. Why not make `input` lower case before comparing with `terminate` instead?

Comment: `std::cout << "This program checks for a balanced expression" << std::endl << "Enter 'end' to end the program" << std::endl;` Don't use `std::endl` when all you want to say is `'\n'` (or `"...\n..."`). `std::endl` not only inserts a newline into the stream but also flushes it. If you \*really\* want to flush a stream be explicit and use `std::flush`. --> `std::cout << "This program checks for a balanced expression\nEnter 'end' to end the program\n";`

Comment: @Swordfish I don't agree with this. For the kinds of programs the performance gain by reducing the number of `endl` is completely 100% not noticeable at all. And for programs where IO performance is important there are a completely different set of tolls and skills applied. All you achieve here is less readability. Not only `<< std::endl` is more readable, `expression\nEnter 'end' to end` makes the **sentences not readable**. Use `<< std::endl`!!

Comment: @bolov And then comes the moment you want to use your program in batch and stdout is suddenly a file. Lots of fun. Being able to read `"expression\nEnter 'end' to end"` as fast and naturally as if there were a space is just a matter of adaption. If you must, for readability: `char const nl{ '\n' };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two things which interrupts work of your code

```
std::transform(terminate.begin(), terminate.end(), terminate.begin(),::toupper); //Extra stuff makes it not case sensitive
```

First of all the logical issue. You perform operation on predefined string *terminate* but you don't change the user input string *input*. In fact you can replace your

```
std::string terminate = "end";
std::transform(terminate.begin(), terminate.end(), terminate.begin(),::toupper); //Extra stuff makes it not case sensitive
```

by one row

```
std::string terminate = "END";
```

And next thing is you change the case of row before reading loop so it can't modify the user input, it only defines initial state of string.
Thus the **position** and **target** of the string modification needs to be modified:

```
int main() {
  std::string input;
  // Replace two initial rows by one with the same result
  std::string terminate = "END";

  std::cout << "This program checks for a balanced expression" << std::endl << "Enter 'end' to end the program" << std::endl;

  while(input != terminate){
    std::cout << "Enter Expression: ";
    std::cin >> input;

    if(checkBalance(input))
      std::cout << input << " " << "is balanced" << std::endl;
    else
      std::cout << input << " " << "is not balanced" << std::endl;

    // Modify user input to upper case for possibility of successful check on next while loop 
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(),::toupper); //Extra stuff makes it not case sensitive

    }

  return 0;
}
```

I located the *input* modification after *checkBalance(input)* since I'm not sure about modifications which it can do for the *input*. In fact the most logical position of the *input* case conversion is directly after reading the string, i.e. after

```
std::cin >> input;
```

One more note. Your initial code should exit for **END** input (i.e. uppercase).